# CSS selector based on a condition

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to get a CSS selector to check and apply the CSS based on the condition that if: `sectionContent-noToolbar` is available, then apply `height:2em` on `sectionSeperator`. Is it possible to achieve that using some selector? I have been searching for an answer for quite a while now without any luck. Any suggestions?

```
<section class="sec" name="Information">
    <div class="sectionContent-noToolbar"></div>
</section>
<div class="sectionSeparator"></div>
```

Comment: General 'is available' conditions don't exist in CSS.

Comment: You cannot apply using CSS since there is no parent selector yet.

Comment: Agreed but is there some other way of getting to it.

Comment: Errr... What every means is that this is unachievable and maybe something you should keep in mind when structuring your site. CSS only work forwards and downwards, no other directions.

Comment: If you provide the class sectionContent-noToolbar to the parent, you can do .sectionContent-noToolbar + .sectionSeparator{} (sibling selector)

Comment: I wish I could but unfortunately I have no control over the HTML. :(

Comment: @TheNewbie I deleted my answer as it is out of context of the title but I think you can get to what you need using margins or padding. http://jsfiddle.net/Manojkr/q9ktf03b/

Comment: @ManojKumar I would also like to add that there is little chance a css selector for parent elements is coming up anytime soon. It was considered, but it is too against the basics of `cascading`.

Answer (score 2):

No, it isn't.

If they were siblings, then you could use the adjacent sibling combinator:

```
.sectionContent-noToolbar + .sectionSeperator {
    height: 2em;
}
```

… but CSS has nothing that lets you modify an element based on its siblings descendants.

Comment: Specifically, there is no parent selector in CSS.

Comment: For typical interpretations of selector syntax at least. selectors-4 makes this possible in theory, even though a "parent selector" (specifically, a counterpart to the child combinator that designates the parent rather than the child as the subject) is nowhere to be found in that specification either.

Comment: @BoltClock I think it was considered, but it causes an enormous amount of headaches with the conditions and ideas behind _Cascading_ Style Sheets.

Comment: @somethinghere: Mostly implementation concerns, which are [still in full force today](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#profiles). Nothing to do with cascading (though at that point I'm just being pedantic...).

Comment: @BoltClock cool, I knew it was mostly a technical issue, but I personally hold the belief that they are cascading as well :) Cheers

Comment: BoltClock is right, it has nothing to do with the cascade. That just determines which *order* rules are applied to a given element in. The implementation issues are with the cost of matching the element in the first place.

Comment: Indeed - though I'm starting to think that attempting to explain what cascading really means in the context of selectors (which is to say, nothing at all) is [an exercise in futility](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector/32858981#comment54592078_1014958) :(

Answer (score 0):

CSS can't help you. You can achieve this with javascript since it can traverse in DOM. jQuery is quite neat for this task. Just select the node you want using css selectors and traversal functions like `parents`, `siblings` or children` and modify the found elements' style manually.

Answer (score -2):

As stated in another answer, there is no way to do this. To achieve the effect you wish to achieve you will need to rethink your implementation. This is because at its core, CSS is not a processed language and as such can not handle conditional statements.

In rethinking, you might look into CSS preprocessors such as [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) or [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) which seek to implement logical constructs in CSS.

Comment: SASS and LESS will have no effect here - they are bound by the same rules as they must output the same language: CSS.

Comment: The title of the question is: "CSS selector based on a condition". SASS and LESS certainly address this.

Comment: @Joshua Cook: If CSS doesn't sufficiently address the problem, neither will any preprocessor, because as somethinghere has said, they all boil down to CSS anyway. I suspect rather than "they will have no effect" they meant to say "they will make no difference", because ultimately this hinges on the capabilities of CSS.

Comment: Nope they do not. SASS or LESS don't output css selectors based on conditions, they generate them based on conditions. The selector is still as defined by CSS as any other. But, yes @BoltClock is right, 'have no effect' might have been incorrect _phrasing_, but thats it.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but these look like conditionals: http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#_8 </pedantic_discussion>

Comment: Those conditions are _unrelated_ to your html and the _output_ is still CSS, which does not allow to do conditional selection like this pseudo one: `body .classExists ? body .class { apply this; } : body .otherClass { apply other; }`. SASS and LESS work, but their end result is just like hand-written CSS.

Comment: Perhaps I should have been clearer. I find that there are multiple approaches to *answering* questions here. There is no EASY solution to this specific problem, as can be seen by the other answer: "No, it isn't." In the absence of an answer, I opted for education. OP is clearly going to need to rethink the implementation of this particular html. IMO pointing at general best practices is a GOOD thing.

Comment: Your answer implies that the tools you recommended can solve the problem, but they can't, so you've just given the OP a big red herring. This can only be done by changing the DOM (either with different HTML or by JavaScript). (The rest of your answer is also wrong, conditions along the similar lines *can* be expressed in CSS, the conditions just can't involve backtracking up the DOM tree).